# MySQL select by id non string

Tags: mysql, sql-injection

I'm using `MySQL` database with `php`. And found something strange.

Ex: I have table `foo` (with auto increment field `id`). When I do: `select * from foo where id='1aoeu';` it's returning `foo`'s row with `id=1`.

And when I do `select * from foo where id='aoeu1';` it's returning nothing.

I think `MySQL` converting `1aoeu` to `int` and returning `1` from that.

How to stop this? Is there any configuration for that?

Comment: You can try not passing in character values into the `WHERE` condition on `id` from your app layer.  Why are you passing in `1aoeu` in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the implementation of Mysql, you need to handle this case on application level. Clients and server side as well(on html form as well as on the server side when you handle this request).